# SQL switch from decode to case

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, case, h2

I have a query that does something like this...

```
SELECT * FROM ...
...
ORDER BY DECODE(APR(ACC.RATE,'X'), 'FIRST RATE', 1, 'SECOND RATE', 2, 3);
```

Because I am dealing with h2 database and h2 doesnt have decode and decode alias is very difficult to implement so I was wondering if I could convert this DECODE into CASE statement. How do I convert it?

Comment: Actually, H2 does support `decode`. But it makes sense to use `case` because that is supported by all databases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decode means:

```
CASE FirstParam
  WHEN SecondParam THEN ThirdParam 
  WHEN FourthParam THEN FifthParam
  WHEN SixthParam THEN Seventh... etcetera
  ELSE LastParam -- If number of params is odd, otherwise ELSE NULL is implied
END
```

So

```
CASE APR(ACC.RATE,'X')
  WHEN 'FIRST RATE' THEN 1
  WHEN 'SECOND RATE' THEN 2
  ELSE 3
END
```

Comment: There is a problem with your ORDER BY clause. Whenever the DECODE uses the default value, then the ordering will not be guaranteed. Your query will have correct ordering only for the values FIRST RATE and SECOND RATE, for values other than these two the order will never be guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

> ORDER BY DECODE(APR(ACC.RATE,'X'), 'FIRST RATE', 1, 'SECOND RATE', 2, 3);

There is a problem with your **ORDER BY** clause. Whenever the **DECODE** uses the `default value`, then the ordering will **not be guaranteed**. Your query will have correct ordering **only** for the values `FIRST RATE` and `SECOND RATE`, for values other than these two the order will never be guaranteed.

It is something like this:

```
FIRST RATE - 1
SECOND RATE - 2
Anything else - 3
```

So, all the values which is now specified to be sorted as `value 3`, will be in **random**.

Better way is:

```
ORDER BY DECODE(APR(ACC.RATE,'X'), 'FIRST RATE', 1, 'SECOND RATE', 2, 3), APR(ACC.RATE,'X')
```

Now, all the rows are **guaranteed** to be always in a specific **order**.

To write the same using **CASE expression**:

```
ORDER BY
CASE (APR(ACC.RATE,'X')
WHEN 'FIRST RATE' THEN
  1
WHEN 'SECOND RATE' THEN
  2
ELSE
  3
END, APR(ACC.RATE,'X')
```

A working **example**:

```
SQL> WITH DATA(id) AS(
  2  SELECT 'X' FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 'A' FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 'Z' FROM dual UNION ALL
  5  SELECT 'M' FROM dual UNION ALL
  6  SELECT 'I' FROM dual UNION ALL
  7  SELECT 'N' FROM dual
  8  )
  9  SELECT * FROM DATA
 10  ORDER BY
 11  CASE id
 12  WHEN 'M' THEN
 13    1
 14  WHEN 'I' THEN
 15    2
 16  WHEN 'N' THEN
 17    3
 18  ELSE
 19    4
 20  END, id
 21  /

I
-
M
I
N
A
X
Z

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: What about if expression APR(ACC.RATE,'X') not gives unique values? To get guaranteed stable (deterministic) rows order just append primary key(s) of selected table(s) to end of "order by" expressions list.