# How to avoid order by in group by query result

Tags: sql, oracle

Below is my query with output:

```
   select  max(urlid) urlid,tbid from  cr.tbdimurl where TBID in(9000493,9000255,9000582,9000341,9000424,9000243,9000257) group by tbid
    urlid   tbid
    ----------------
    23229   9000243
    8792    9000255
    8800    9000257
    20756   9000341
    25431   9000424
    23797   9000493
    33458   9000582
```

I want the query result sorted in the order of  list of TBID's as mentioned in subquery . Column urlid have clustered index define on it and there is no index defined on column TBID.

As the values in subquery are dynamic i cannot use case expression for sorting.

Is there any way I can avoid the default sorting?

Comment: [You have to have an `order by` clause](http://tkyte.blogspot.co.uk/2005/08/order-in-court.html) to guarantee the result set ordering.

Comment: There is no default sorting, you must have an **ORDER BY** clause to sort the output. If you want customized sorting, then you need to use **CASE** expression in `ORDER BY`.

Comment: I can't use CASE expression as the values are dynamic

Comment: @AlexPoole The answers in the post marked as duplicate are not good because for values other than mentioned in the CASE, the order will never be guaranteed. Something like http://stackoverflow.com/a/30702085/3989608 This is something once you noted in one of my answers, since then I always remember this :-)

Comment: @LalitKumarB - the answers on the linked question include all the possible values (from the where clause) in the case/decode, so there is no default or any ordering from values that aren't included. They may not make it entirely clear that the case has to be expanded to cover new values added to the where I suppose, but I think it was implied. My answer is more dynamic but not guaranteed to work, as I noted *8-)

Comment: @AlexPoole Oops, I didn't notice your answer. It was *sorted* in the end, I missed it.

Comment: Seems appropriate *8-)